# Corona SDK: Inserting into tables

Tags: coronasdk

I've read the other topics related to this subject and cannot make sense of them in the sense of my code.  In the code below, I cannot get the **make other word buttons** into the table.  I can generate the words but they will not go into the table.  The previous function with the correct word works fine.  What am I doing wrong?  Do I have problems elsewhere in the code?

```
--main text

local content = require "content"

--chooses a random number according to the maximum number available in the table

local defaultWidth = 1024
local defaultHeight = 768
local displayWidth = display.viewableContentWidth
local displayHeight = display.viewableContentHeight
local yMargin = 20
local centerX = defaultWidth/2;
local centerY = defaultHeight/2;
local xAdjust = (defaultWidth - display.viewableContentWidth)/2
local yAdjust = (defaultHeight - display.viewableContentHeight)/2
local rnd = math.random
local maxSightwords = 3
local currQuestion = 0
local playOrder
local letterButtons
local wrongGraphic
local correctButton
--local wordButtons


function getRandomOrder(amount)
    local order ={}
    local i
    local temp
    local temp1
    for n = 1,amount do
        order[n] = n
    end
    for i=0,9 do
        for temp = 1,amount do
            n = math.random(1, amount)
            temp1 = order[temp]
            order[temp] = order[n]
            order[n] = temp1
        end
    end
    return order

end 

    -- assign random order for words
    playOrder = getRandomOrder(#content)


function nextQuestion()

    -- update question number index
    currQuestion = currQuestion+1
    if currQuestion > #playOrder then
        currQuestion = 1
    end

    local questionNumber = playOrder[currQuestion]

    print("Question# "..currQuestion)
    print("id "..content[questionNumber].id)

    -- make word buttons
    wordButtons = {}

    -- make word button for correct word
    local word = content[playOrder[currQuestion]].word
    table.insert(wordButtons, newWordButton(word))
    correctButton = wordButtons[1].graphics
    local buttonWidth = 150

    print ("correct: "..word)
    print (#wordButtons)


    ---[[
    -- ****make other word buttons***
    local otherWords = getRandomWords(content.word)

    --print (otherWords)
    for i=1, maxSightwords-1 do
        table.insert(wordButtons, otherWords)

    end
    --]]
    print (#wordButtons)



    -- position letter buttons and add touch event listener
    local randomWordOrder = getRandomOrder(#wordButtons)
    local buttonSpacing = buttonWidth * 1.5
    local buttonsWidth = (#wordButtons * buttonWidth) + ((#wordButtons-1) * (buttonSpacing/4))
    local buttonsX = centerX - (buttonWidth)
    for i=1, #wordButtons do
        local button = wordButtons[i].graphics
        button.y = centerY
        button.x = buttonsX + (buttonSpacing * (randomWordOrder[i]-1))
        button:addEventListener("touch", onWordTouch)
        --local randomDelay = transitionDuration + (math.random(1,10) * 10)
        --transition.from(button, {time = 500, delay = randomDelay, y = defaultHeight + button.height})
    end

end

function clearQuestion()
    -- remove wrongGraphic if present
    if wrongGraphic then
        wrongGraphic:removeSelf()
        wrongGraphic = nil
    end

    -- remove all word buttons
    for i=1,#wordButtons do
        wordButtons[i].graphics:removeSelf()
        wordButtons[i].graphics = nil
    end
end


function onWordTouch(event)
    local t = event.target
    if "ended" == event.phase then
        if t == correctButton then
            onCorrect()
        else
            onIncorrect(t)
        end

    end
end

function onIncorrect(incorrectButton)
    media.playSound("sounds/splat.wav")
    wrongGraphic = display.newImageRect("images/graphics/wrong.png", 137, 136)
    wrongGraphic.x = incorrectButton.x + incorrectButton.width/2
    wrongGraphic.y = incorrectButton.y + incorrectButton.height/2
    transition.to(incorrectButton, {time=100, delay=500, alpha=0})
    transition.to(wrongGraphic, {time=200, delay=500, alpha=0, onComplete=wrongCompleteListener})
    local wrongCompleteListener = function(obj)
       obj:removeSelf()
       obj = nil
       incorrectButton:removeSelf()
       incorrectButton = nil
    end
end

function onCorrect()
    -- play correct sound then display word
    media.playSound("sounds/correct.mp3", playWord)

    -- remove the letter buttons
    clearQuestion()

    -- disable the home button until new screen is shown
    homeEnabled = false
end



function newWordButton(word)
    local wordGraphic = display.newImageRect("images/words/"..word..".png", 150, 75)
    local wordButton = {}
    wordButton.graphics = display.newGroup()
    wordButton.graphics:insert(wordGraphic)
    wordButton.word = word
    return wordButton   
end

function getRandomWords ()
    local wordGraphic = display.newGroup ()
    for i=1,maxSightwords-1 do
    --remove a word from content using a random index #
    --Since the index will be between 1 and the number of words in content
    --and each time through the loop a word is removed, you can be sure
    --You will get 3 different words without repeats.
    local next_word = table.remove(content, math.random(#content))

    --next_word is a table with 'word' and 'id' fields so you can make the text display object from next_word.word
    local wordText = display.newImageRect("images/words/"..next_word.id..".png", 150, 75)
            wordText.x = display.contentWidth/2
            wordText.y = display.contentHeight/2 - 100
            wordGraphic:insert(wordText)
        print (next_word.id)
    end 
end

nextQuestion ()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are resetting the `wordButton = {}` again in function `newWordButton`.  You already made the table in `function nextQuestion()`, so by calling it again in the newWordButton function is reseting the entire table.

Take a look at this links:

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/06/21/understanding-lua-tables-in-corona-sdk/

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/table/insert.html

I'm pretty sure the function should look like this:

```
function newWordButton(word)
    local wordGraphic = display.newImageRect("images/words/"..word..".png", 150, 75)
    wordButton.graphics = display.newGroup()
    wordButton.graphics:insert(wordGraphic)
    wordButton.word = word
    return wordButton   
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but the tables are actually different: wordButtons and wordButton

Comment: Oh my bad didn't notice that. Still though, those links should help you solve your problem. You might want to create a separate document and try to just insert the values you want into the table, then put it in your code.

Comment: It seems to be something about the value or keys created in the random word functions.  I've checked the tutorials you mentioned and found some others but still cannot get it figured out.